# Don't know why this stream() not working on this nested list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two nested List type as here:

```
    List<Team> team;
    
    public class Team{
        private String teamId;
        private List<TeamUsers> teamUsers;
        --getter setter...
    }

    
    public class TeamUsers{
        private int TeamUsersId;
        private int active;
        --getter setter...

    }
```

I want to return all List, and inside each Team object, if the TeamUsers object active = 0, then don't return this TeamUsers object in the nested List.
Here is my code:

```
List<Team> alldata = (List<Team>) teamRepo.findAll();
List<Team> finalResult = alldata.stream()
                .filter(a -> a.getTeam_users().stream().allMatch(b -> b.getActive() == 1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's only return me the first team which all TeamUsers.active = 1.

In the second Team I do have some TeamUsers.active = 1 and some TeamUsers.active = 0.

What mistake I made?

Comment: `.allMatch()` returns `true` only if **all** elements of the `Stream` match the `Predicate`. You might want to use `.anyMatch()`.

Comment: @dan1st thanks, but I tried to use .anyMatch but it returns me all data even active = 0....

Comment: You are filtering teams. This way, you can either get the whole team or ignore the team. You can use `.map()` if you want to get modified teams (with active users only).

Comment: Or, if you just want to get the users, you can use `flatMap()` to get a `Stream<TeamUsers>` and filter that.

Comment: You also shouldn't use `int` when you mean `boolean`, and if you're casting the result of `findAll`, your declaration needs to be fixed.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- . are you saying that I should't use int type as Active flag? I agree with you I will mark that down and modify my entity. 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to modify the user lists:

```java
List<Team> alldata = (List<Team>) teamRepo.findAll();

List<Team> finalResult = alldata.stream()
        .map(t -> new Team(t.getTeamId(),
                           t.getTeamUsers().stream()
                                   .filter(u -> u.getActive() == 1)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .filter(t -> t.getTeamUsers().size() != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some similar code. Using the Java 16+ [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature for brevity, but that is not necessary.

`Member` class.

```java
package work.basil.team;

public record Member( int id , String name , int status ) { } // Status: 0=inactive, 1=active.
```

`Team` class.

```java
package work.basil.team;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public record Team( UUID id , String name , List < Member > memberList ) { }
```

Populate some data.

```java
Team alphaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "b4c94867-8ac7-4caf-bf49-b79df92cff82" ) ,
        "Alpha",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        1 ,
                        "Alice",
                        1
                ),
                new Member(
                        2 ,
                        "Bob",
                        1
                )
        )
);

Team betaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "9d12160a-94cc-45c6-a465-12cdf3d1a503" ) ,
        "Beta",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        3,
                        "Carol",
                        0
                ),
                new Member(
                        4,
                        "Davis",
                        1
                )
        )
);

Team gammaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "f440ac2d-9175-47d8-a5e2-3102e0d162bc" ) ,
        "Gamma",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        5 ,
                        "Ernestine",
                        1
                ),
                new Member(
                        6 ,
                        "Frank",
                        1
                )
        )
);

List < Team > teams = List.of( alphaTeam , betaTeam , gammaTeam );
```

Code to report on that collection of teams to find only those teams where all the members are active. Our logic here is flipped, testing where we do *not* find any members with inactive status.

```java
List<Team> teamsWhoseMembershipIsEntirelyActive =
        teams
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        team -> ! team.memberList().stream().anyMatch( member -> member.status() == 0 )
                )
                .toList()
;
```

> teamsWhoseMembershipIsEntirelyActive = [Team[id=b4c94867-8ac7-4caf-bf49-b79df92cff82, name=Alpha, memberList=[Member[id=1, name=Alice, status=1], Member[id=2, name=Bob, status=1]]], Team[id=f440ac2d-9175-47d8-a5e2-3102e0d162bc, name=Gamma, memberList=[Member[id=5, name=Ernestine, status=1], Member[id=6, name=Frank, status=1]]]]

You could just as well drop the `!` *not* operator, and use a predicate with `.allMatch` rather than `.anyMatch` aimed at values of `1` rather than `0`.

```java
List<Team> teamsWhoseMembershipIsEntirelyActive =
        teams
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        team -> team.memberList().stream().allMatch( member -> member.status() == 1 )
                )
                .toList()
;
```

---

By the way, better to use Java’s enum facility rather than a mere `int` for your active/inactive status.

Using an enum provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), ensures valid values, and makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Change the `Member` class to nest an enum definition. Enum objects are constants, and so are named in all-caps per Java naming conventions.

```java
package work.basil.team;

public record Member( int id , String name , Status status ) {
    public enum Status { ACTIVE , INACTIVE, UNKNOWN }
}
```

Change our data populating code to use the enum objects.

```java
Team alphaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "b4c94867-8ac7-4caf-bf49-b79df92cff82" ) ,
        "Alpha",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        1 ,
                        "Alice",
                        Member.Status.ACTIVE
                ),
                new Member(
                        2 ,
                        "Bob",
                        Member.Status.ACTIVE
                )
        )
);

Team betaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "9d12160a-94cc-45c6-a465-12cdf3d1a503" ) ,
        "Beta",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        3,
                        "Carol",
                        Member.Status.INACTIVE
                ),
                new Member(
                        4,
                        "Davis",
                        Member.Status.ACTIVE
                )
        )
);

Team gammaTeam = new Team(
        UUID.fromString(  "f440ac2d-9175-47d8-a5e2-3102e0d162bc" ) ,
        "Gamma",
        List.of(
                new Member(
                        5 ,
                        "Ernestine",
                        Member.Status.ACTIVE
                ),
                new Member(
                        6 ,
                        "Frank",
                        Member.Status.ACTIVE
                )
        )
);

List < Team > teams = List.of( alphaTeam , betaTeam , gammaTeam );
```

Change our predicate to test for an enum object rather than an `int` number.

```java
List<Team> teamsWhoseMembershipIsEntirelyActive =
        teams
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        team -> team.memberList().stream().allMatch( member -> member.status().equals( Member.Status.ACTIVE ) )
                )
                .toList()
;
```

See this code converted to Java 12 and [running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/b6gkMj).

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, unfortunately I have to mark andreas's answer and the end because I deploye his solution first. I really appreciate your answer sir.

Comment: unfortuntely I tried your code but it is not working. 
It basically the same logic as my original code I posted. it won't filter on the active attributes.

Comment: @PEIRANLIU I have run all my examples here multiple times. In all my results I get the Alpha & Gamma teams, while omitting the Beta team that has one member Carol as inactive. Notice my edits regarding flipping the logic: Either make the predicate "NOT contains *any* inactive", or make the predicate "Contains *all* active".  Your choice, either works given the domain values seen here (only two values 0 or 1) — if you have other values in play then which way you flip the logic *does* matter. If still confused, grab some paper, write some data, and trace through manually.

Comment: @PEIRANLIU I converted all that code to Java 12 so you can see the [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/b6gkMj).

Comment: Thanks I just checked your source code by using Enum. it is very freshing and I decide to convert to this approach.
But the only thing I want to point out is, maybe I didn't expain the questions very clear, my bad. 
I want to return all teams with their active user. for example we have 2 team, first team have 2 user and they are all active then we return the team with those two users.
but, second team has 2 user and only one user is active, we still return the second team and it should only contain that active user.

Comment: @PEIRANLIU No, your Question was not clear on that point. My code is built for immutable data (`record` & `List.of`).